# QtCreator + Qbs + IAR

Tags: qt, qt-creator, iar, qbs

I have a project on old IAR version and basically I want to use QtCreator for editing and building the project. IAR have a custom compiler and linker. It's CR16 platform, so my case is really unusual. How to archive this goal?

I tried already qbs and it's not working for me. As I understood it works with gcc compiler only and I don't know how to configure it. I also configured a compiler https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxgcZhMUJY8_NHh1SlduZENkTFk/view and made a kit https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxgcZhMUJY8_dFp3dFlRSnJnMm8/view

On this point I don't need debugger support, only building, support of build configuration there I can include or exclude files from build, and see an errors from build.

I tried to import generic project but it's not what I need, it just a code editor with some strange syntax errors (I have no such errors in IAR). So I thought I need qbs or cmake project and import everything in it.

I read info by this link http://habrahabr.ru/post/258467/ and possibly all information about Qt baremetal + gcc compiler. But I didn't find anything about how to use non-gcc compiler and how you need to configure Qt for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a `Rule {}` to compile IAR.

https://doc.qt.io/qbs/rule-item.html

Here's another [example](https://github.com/Cavewhere/cavewhere/blob/master/src/qbs/protoBuffer/ProtoBuffer.qbs) from my Cavewhere project. I have protobuffer files that need to be compiled into cpp and h files. The `Depends { name: "cpp" }`picks artifacts from protobuffer rules and compiles them into object artifacts.

You can do the same thing with IAR. You just have to tag the files properly with `Group { fileTags: "iarFiles" }` and then write a `Rule { }` that takes `iarFiles` as an input.

Answer (score 1):

Right now (since Qbs 1.15, AFAIK), it is possible to use the IAR toolchain in QBS. Also it is supported in QtCreator and VSCode IDEs.